# Tool which stores the journal of systemd in a PostgreSQL table

Tags: linux, logs, postgresql, journal

I search a tool which stores the journal (logs) of systemd in a PostgreSQL table.

Required features:

- open source
- No single log entry should get lost
- No duplicates should get created.
- efficient: N log entries should get inserted to the database table in one SQL statement
- The db schema should be able handle the logs of several hosts in one database table.